# dygraph function - how to make zoom in at multipul graphs at the same time

Tags: javascript, graph, dygraphs

I have three diffrent graphs for the same X label (date time lable).
I want to do zoom in (with the mouse) on one graph  and see the zoom on all of the three.

can it be done? what are the  major steps?

Thanks

Comment: Ave you solved? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to register a drawCallback function, which you can use to copy the scale and pan to all linked plots. [There's an example here](http://dygraphs.com/tests/synchronize.html) of this technique.